# Input/output (read) errors in Bacula while setting up a Tape Drive + Autochanger

Tags: linux, backup, bacula

When running the `label barcode` command in bacula I am getting Input/output errors. I am just getting started in trying to set this up:

```
Connecting to Storage daemon TapeDevice at ny-back01.ny.stackoverflow.com:9103 ...
Sending label command for Volume "ACJ332" Slot 1 ...
3307 Issuing autochanger "unload slot 8, drive 0" command.
3304 Issuing autochanger "load slot 1, drive 0" command.
3305 Autochanger "load slot 1, drive 0", status is OK.
block.c:1010 Read error on fd=5 at file:blk 0:0 on device "ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0). ERR=Input/output error.
3000 OK label. VolBytes=64512 DVD=0 Volume="ACJ332" Device="ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0)
Catalog record for Volume "ACJ332", Slot 1  successfully created.
Sending label command for Volume "ACJ331" Slot 2 ...
3307 Issuing autochanger "unload slot 1, drive 0" command.
3304 Issuing autochanger "load slot 2, drive 0" command.
3305 Autochanger "load slot 2, drive 0", status is OK.
block.c:1010 Read error on fd=5 at file:blk 0:0 on device "ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0). ERR=Input/output error.
3000 OK label. VolBytes=64512 DVD=0 Volume="ACJ331" Device="ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0)
Catalog record for Volume "ACJ331", Slot 2  successfully created.
Sending label command for Volume "ACJ328" Slot 3 ...
3307 Issuing autochanger "unload slot 2, drive 0" command.
3304 Issuing autochanger "load slot 3, drive 0" command.
3305 Autochanger "load slot 3, drive 0", status is OK.
block.c:1010 Read error on fd=5 at file:blk 0:0 on device "ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0). ERR=Input/output error.
3000 OK label. VolBytes=64512 DVD=0 Volume="ACJ328" Device="ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0)
Catalog record for Volume "ACJ328", Slot 3  successfully created.
Sending label command for Volume "ACJ329" Slot 4 ...
3307 Issuing autochanger "unload slot 3, drive 0" command.
3304 Issuing autochanger "load slot 4, drive 0" command.
3305 Autochanger "load slot 4, drive 0", status is OK.
block.c:1010 Read error on fd=5 at file:blk 0:0 on device "ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0). ERR=Input/output error.
3000 OK label. VolBytes=64512 DVD=0 Volume="ACJ329" Device="ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0)
Catalog record for Volume "ACJ329", Slot 4  successfully created.
Sending label command for Volume "ACJ335" Slot 5 ...
3307 Issuing autochanger "unload slot 4, drive 0" command.
3304 Issuing autochanger "load slot 5, drive 0" command.
3305 Autochanger "load slot 5, drive 0", status is OK.
block.c:1010 Read error on fd=5 at file:blk 0:0 on device "ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0). ERR=Input/output error.
3000 OK label. VolBytes=64512 DVD=0 Volume="ACJ335" Device="ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0)
Catalog record for Volume "ACJ335", Slot 5  successfully created.
Sending label command for Volume "ACJ334" Slot 6 ...
3307 Issuing autochanger "unload slot 5, drive 0" command.
3304 Issuing autochanger "load slot 6, drive 0" command.
3305 Autochanger "load slot 6, drive 0", status is OK.
block.c:1010 Read error on fd=5 at file:blk 0:0 on device "ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0). ERR=Input/output error.
3000 OK label. VolBytes=64512 DVD=0 Volume="ACJ334" Device="ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0)
Catalog record for Volume "ACJ334", Slot 6  successfully created.
Sending label command for Volume "ACJ333" Slot 7 ...
3307 Issuing autochanger "unload slot 6, drive 0" command.
3304 Issuing autochanger "load slot 7, drive 0" command.
3305 Autochanger "load slot 7, drive 0", status is OK.
block.c:1010 Read error on fd=5 at file:blk 0:0 on device "ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0). ERR=Input/output error.
3000 OK label. VolBytes=64512 DVD=0 Volume="ACJ333" Device="ULTRIUM-HH4" (/dev/st0)
Catalog record for Volume "ACJ333", Slot 7  successfully created.
Sending label command for Volume "ACJ330" Slot 8 ...
3307 Issuing autochanger "unload slot 7, drive 0" command.
```

Bacula-dir:

```
    # Definition of file storage device
    Storage {
      Name = TapeDevice
    # Do not use "localhost" here    
      Address = ny-back01....     # N.B. Use a fully qualified name here
      SDPort = 9103
      Password = "..."
      Device = ULTRIUM-HH4
      Media Type = LTO-4
      Media Type = File
      Autochanger = Yes
    }
```

Bacula-sd:

```
Autochanger {
        Name = StorageLoader1U
        Device = ULTRIUM-HH4
        Changer Command = "/etc/bacula/scripts/mtx-changer %c %o %S %a %d"
        Changer Device = /dev/sg5
}

Device {
        Name = ULTRIUM-HH4
        Media Type = LTO-4
        Archive Device = /dev/st0
        AutomaticMount = yes;
        AlwaysOpen = yes;
        RemovableMedia = yes;
        RandomAccess = no;
        AutoChanger = yes;
        RandomAccess = no;
}
```

Anyone knows what this means / why I am getting this?

Comment: Oops ... have media type twice in the director config

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so because of the following config error:

```
  Media Type = LTO-4
  Media Type = File
```

I confused bacula it seems. The media was listed from the `list media` command as type File. So what I did was drop the pool and then try to rescan with `label barcode`. However, it was refused because the tapes already had the bacula volume lablel on them. To fix this I made this little loop:

```
for i in $(seq 1 8); do 
    /etc/bacula/scripts/mtx-changer /dev/sg5 load $i /dev/st0 0
    mt -f /dev/st0 rewind
    mt -f /dev/st0 weof
    /etc/bacula/scripts/mtx-changer /dev/sg5 unload $i /dev/st0 0
done
```

I was then able to run the `label barcode` again this time without the original error or the "3920 Cannot label Volume because it is already labeled" error.